# Undefined variable that is defined in the constructor

Tags: php

Hi I seem to be getting an error on my code that seems to say that I have not initialez my variable but th veriabile is initialized in the constructor:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\Tutorials\Login\classes\mysql.php on line 18

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\Tutorials\Login\classes\mysql.php on line 18
```

And this is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('includes/constants.php');
    class Mysql{

        private $conn;

        function __construct() {
            $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER , DB_USER , DB_PASSWORD , DB_NAME) or 
                   die('There was a problem connecting to the database');
        }
        function verify_Username_and_Pass($un , $pwd){

            $query = "SELECT * 
                      FROM users
                      WHERE username = ? AND password= ?
                      LIMIT 1";

            if($stmt = $this->$conn->prepare($query)){ //this is where the error points
                $stmt->bind_param('ss', $un, $pwd);
                $stmt->execute();

                if($stmt->fetch()){
                    $stmt->close;
                    return true;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
?>
```

The error is thrown at the first if statement.How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
$this->$conn
```

with

```
$this->conn
```

on the line when you have the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->$conn
```

This is wrong, it should be

```
$this->conn
```